# Error Using Apply Function to Create a New Column Based on Multiple Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write an if, elif function to determine a student's college selectivity based on their GPA and SAT score. My dataframe has the students' names as the index, their GPA, and their SAT score. I want to create a new column that states their selectivity. I thought at first I was messing up my and vs &, but have tried it a few different ways and keep getting: TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.

Here is my code:

```
def f(x):
    if x['GPA W'] < 2.0 & x['SAT'] == NaN:return "2 yr"
    elif x['GPA W'] < 2.0 & x['SAT'] < 940:return "2 yr"
    elif x['GPA W'] < 2.0 & x['SAT'] >= 940 & x['SAT']<= 1050: return "Non-Selective 4 yr"
    elif x['GPA W'] < 2.0 & x['SAT'] >= 1060 & x['SAT']<= 1150:return "Somewhat Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] < 2.0 & x['SAT'] >=1160:return "Somewhat Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.0 and x['GPA W']<=2.4 & x['SAT'] == NaN:return "Non-Selective 4 yr"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.0 and x['GPA W']<=2.4 & x['SAT'] < 940:return "Non-Selective 4 yr"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.0 and x['GPA W']<=2.4 & x['SAT'] >= 940 and x['SAT'] <= 1050:return "Somewhat Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.0 and x['GPA W']<=2.4 & x['SAT'] >= 1060 and x['SAT']<= 1150:return "Somewhat Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.0 and x['GPA W']<=2.4 & x['SAT'] > 1160:return "Selective/Very Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.5 and x['GPA W']<=2.9 & x['SAT'] == NaN:return "Somewhat Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.5 and x['GPA W']<=2.9 & x['SAT'] < 940:return "Somewhat Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.5 and x['GPA W']<=2.9 & x['SAT'] >= 940 and x['SAT']<= 1050:return "Somewhat Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.5 and x['GPA W']<=2.9 & x['SAT'] >= 1060 and x['SAT']<= 1150:return "Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 2.5 and x['GPA W']<=2.9 & x['SAT'] > 1160:return "Selective/Very Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.0 and x['GPA W']<=3.4 & x['SAT'] == NaN:return "Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.0 and x['GPA W']<=3.4 & x['SAT'] < 940:return "Somewhat Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.0 and x['GPA W']<=3.4 & x['SAT'] >= 940 and x['SAT']<= 1050:return "Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.0 and x['GPA W']<=3.4 & x['SAT'] >= 1060 and x['SAT']<= 1150:return "Selective/Very Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.0 and x['GPA W']<=3.4 & x['SAT'] > 1160:return "Very Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.5 and x['GPA W']<=4.0 & x['SAT'] == NaN:return "Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.5 and x['GPA W']<=4.0 & x['SAT'] < 940:return "Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.5 and x['GPA W']<=4.0 & x['SAT'] >= 940 and x['SAT']<= 1050:return "Selective/Very Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.5 and x['GPA W']<=4.0 & x['SAT'] >= 1060 and x['SAT']<= 1150:return "Selective/Very Selective"
    elif x['GPA W'] >= 3.5 and x['GPA W']<=4.0 & x['SAT'] > 1160:return "Very Selective"
    else:return "Unknown"
dat['Selectivity'] = dat.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: If I can make a suggestion as well, I would split up the blocks of the code there. Notice how you repeat `x['GPA W'] < 2.0` and `x['GPA W'] >= 2.0` a lot of times. You can create an outer set of `if` statements on these alone so make stuff cleaner. Example:
```
if x['GPA W'] < 2.0:
    if x['SAT'] < 940: return "2 yr"
    elif ...
elif 2.0 <= x['GPA W'] <= 2.4:
    if x['SAT'] == NaN: return "BlahBlahBlah"
    etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `&` refers to "bitwise and" - which means that each bit between its arguments are "anded". Example would be

```
  0b01 & 0b11 == 0b01
```

You want to use a "logical and" there, which in python is simply the word `and`. So just convert all of your `&`s to `and`s and I think you should be good.

Comment: I will give it a try! Thank you! For the suggestion about breaking up the code, can you provide an example of what that would look like?

Comment: something like this! https://gist.github.com/Axel-Jacobsen/1ef17ce1b8243b22557f43c975452be3

Comment: That does look a lot cleaner. Thanks for the help!